# Gulpjs – gulp-jade compilation issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

I got an error I can't figure out while using the gulpJs module *gulp-jade*

```
> [11:13:59] TypeError: listener must be a function
>     at DestroyableTransform.addListener (events.js:197:11)
>     at DestroyableTransform.Readable.on (/Users/ME/Sites/temp/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:718:33)
>     at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/ME/Sites/temp/gulpfile.js:14:16)
>     at module.exports (/Users/ME/Sites/temp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
>     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/ME/Sites/temp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
>     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/ME/Sites/temp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
>     at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/ME/Sites/temp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
>     at doNTCallback0 (node.js:428:9)
>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:357:13)
```

I have correctly installed the module and my gulpfile is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('markup', function() {
  gulp.src('jade/**/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade().on('error', jade.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/build'));
});
```

Comment: So `jade.logError` isn't a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `.pipe(jade().on('error', jade.logError))` - I believe `jade` does not contain anything like `logError`. Try something like this: `.pipe(jade().on('error', console.log))`

Comment: right, works by deleting that line... but my code doesnt compile to html yet... just make a copy of my jade file into /build/

Comment: forgot to really .pipe(jade()) :)